# Edit page to display all category names with edit inputs on each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have categories nested inside of guides. I'm building an app to learn rails better and I'm trying to make a page that will display all categories that belong to a guide and have edit inputs under them and a save button next to it so the user can edit the names of the categories they want to change.

Bit stuck on how exactly how get this done.

here is the category_item_keys controller

```
def edit
 @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
 @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
 @key = @category.category_item_keys
end

def update

 @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
 @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
 @key = @category.category_item_keys.friendly.find(key_params) # no idea what to make this equal because it isn't one set key being edited on the page


 if @key =  @category.category_item_keys.update_attributes(key_params)
  flash[:success] = "Key updated"
  redirect_to @guide
 else
  render 'edit'
 end

end

private

def key_params
params.require(:category_item_key).permit(:key, :slug)
end
```

routes

```
match '/guides/:guide_id/:category_id/keys/edit' => 'category_item_keys#edit', :via => :get
match '/guides/:guide_id/:category_id/keys/' => 'category_item_keys#update', :via => :post, as: :category_item_keys_update
```

edit.html.erb

```
  <ul>
<% @key.each do |key| %>

  <li><%= key.key #just shows key name %><br>
    <%= form_for([@category, @keys], url: category_item_keys_create_path) do |f| %>
       <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :key, "Key name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :key %>

      <%= f.submit "Save"  %>
    <% end %>
    </li>


<% end %>
  </ul>
```

This just gives me an error of:

```
undefined method `to_key' for #<CategoryItemKey::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fe20a86b480>
```

Later I plan on using an in-place editor gem but i would like to learn how this can be done fist.

**EDIT:**

Fixed the error ( changed `form_for([@category, @keys]` to `form_for([@category, key]` and turns out this way works for displaying and allowing all categories to be edited... to an extent.

I get another error when i submit a form
`undefined method 'update_attribute'`

**EDIT 2**
slowly getting there. I Changed the update @key variable to `@key = @category.category_item_keys.all` to fix the error. But this line is now giving me problems

`if @key =  @category.category_item_keys.update_attributes(key_params)`'

**THIRD EDIT**

ERROR

```
Couldn't find CategoryItemKey without an ID
```

on line

```
@key     = @category.category_item_keys.find params[:id]
```

paramaters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"egj/OebdSbxxaoaTkr46WVIOIIu4Ezijzu45kqxLT0krjFWHqi67SRJDSgV7bcL6SeoGpUSYsrolspylCXBu9g==",
 "category_item_key"=>{"name"=>"def1111"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "guide_id"=>"dbz",
 "category_id"=>"characters"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to clean up the code:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :guides do
    resources :categories, path: "" do
       resources :category_item_keys, path: "keys", only: [:update] do
          get :edit, on: :collection #-> url.com/guides/:guide_id/:category_id/keys/edit
       end
    end
end

#app/controllers/keys_controller.rb
class KeysController < ApplicationController
    def edit
        @guide    = Guide.find params[:guide_id]
        @category = Category.find params[:category_id]
        @keys     = @category.category_item_keys
    end

    def update
        @guide    = Guide.find params[:guide_id]
        @category = Category.find params[:category_id]
        @key      = @category.category_item_keys.find params[:id] 

        if @key.update key_params
           redirect_to @guide, success: "Key Updated"
        else
           render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private

    def key_params
       params.require(:category_item_key).permit(:key)
    end
end

#app/views/keys/edit.html.erb
<% @keys.each do |key| %>
   <%= form_for [@guide, @category, key] do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :key %>
      <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

If you wanted to use an `in-place` editor gem, I'd recommend looking at [`X-Editable`](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/), as we've applied it [here](http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com) (its only a demo app, just sign up for free and go to profile):

[image]

Comment: get the error `Couldn't find CategoryItemKey without an ID` on line `@key     = @category.category_item_keys.find params[:id] ` added the parameters to the question

Comment: What's the url the form sends you to?

Comment: url is http://localhost:3000/guides/dbz/characters/keys or do you mean the url path?

Comment: Noo, I'm just interested why the `update` path doesn't take the `id`. Are your routes as I put them in the answer?

Comment: if i change the routes to your answer i get the error `uninitialized constant KeysController`.

Comment: Updated my routes, sorry I didn't realized you had a different controller name

Comment: Works! That nested resources  route looks out of my league, ill have to give the rails routes page a good reading tomorrow to better understand them. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Np the routes stuff is really quite simple - just keep doing it a lot and you'll get used to it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to do `update_attributes` on a collection instead of an object. Try to first fetch the key object

```
@key = @category.category_item_keys.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

and then try to update its attributes

```
if @key.update_attributes(key_params)
    ...
end
```

Comment: I think you might be right, im just having problems with friendly id. its not saving the slug for some reason. ill come back when i sort it out, looks like i might have to change the 'key' column name to 'name'

Comment: It throws the error `Couldn't find CategoryItemKey without an ID`

Comment: What does the code look like where it throws that error?

Comment: ` @key = @category.category_item_keys.friendly.find(params[:id])` the line you wanted me to change

Comment: Ok, what does the params hash look like? Maybe :id is nil for some reason.

Comment: added the params to the question

Comment: Looks like params[:id] is nil then. Change the line to `@key = @category.category_item_keys.friendly.find(params[:category_item_key][:name])`

Comment: error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` I think because its doing the find before the db is undated it cant find the categroy_item_keys with those params which is the updated name

Comment: Another answer fixed my problem. Thanks anyway for the help, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

use [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) available in rails 4.

Comment: It looks like it creates a category as well as a key. i only need to edit keys.

Comment: then just remove the fields what you don`t want to edit.