# No slug being added with friendly id rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, friendly-id

When i create a new category_item_key in the db the slug isn't being added to the slug column.

here is my coding

migration file

```
class AddSlugToCategoryItemKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    add_column :category_item_keys, :slug, :string
    add_index :category_item_keys,  :slug, unique: true
  end

end
```

category_item_key controller

```
def new
 @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
 @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
 @key = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id]).category_item_keys.new

end

def create

 @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
 @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
 @key = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id]).category_item_keys.new(key_params)


  if @key.save
       flash[:info] = "Key added succesfully!"
      redirect_to @guide
  else
      render 'new'
  end
end



private


def key_params
 params.require(:category_item_key).permit(:name, :slug)
end
```

new.html.erb

```
     <%= form_for([@category, @key], url: category_item_keys_create_path) do |f| %>
       <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :name, "Key name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.submit "Next"  %>
    <% end %>
```

When creating a new guide or category friendly id works just fine, with the slug being added. But for category_item_key something is going wrong.

Maybe i'm missing something. But i cant find the problem.

Comment: Please update your question with `category_item_key.rb` model code.

Comment: I forgot to add      `extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged` into my model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def new
   @guide    = Guide.find params[:guide_id]
   @category = Category.find params[:category_id]
   @key      = @category.category_item_keys.new
end

def create
   @guide    = Guide.find params[:guide_id]
   @category = Category.find params[:category_id]
   @key      = @category.category_item_keys.new key_params

   if @key.save
      redirect_to @guide, notice: "Key added succesfully!"
   else
      render 'new'
   end
end

private

def key_params
   params.require(:category_item_key).permit(:name)
end
```

--

```
<%= form_for [@guide, @category, @key] do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :name, "Key name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.submit "Next"  %>
<% end %>
```

If you've ran your migration (have the columns in the db), the above should work. If it doesn't, you need to post the sent params, and the response you're receiving from the server.

--

As an aside, you'll also want to [look at how many levels you're nesting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) your routes...

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

Because you've got `guides` and then `categories` before you get to `keys`, you'll probably want to remove the `category` or `guide` param:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :categories do
   resources :keys
end
```

I think the issue you have is *likely* that you're only passing `[@category, @key]` to your `form_for`. Instead, you'll need to include the `@guide` as well.

Comment: The variables don't work now because they arer't using friendly.find. and thanks for the side note

Comment: Then just put `friendly_id: [[column]], use: [:slugged, :finders]` in your model

Comment: adding      `extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged` into my model did the trick (swear i checked it was there). Thanks for your help. You showed me a cleaner way of coding and stopped me from creating a nested resource nightmare

Comment: haha thanks man. A pro tip - you don't even need that in your model; if you go to `config/initializers/friendly_id`, you can set `config.use :slugged` which applies to all models. So you'll just be able to use `friendly_id :x` in your model with inpunity

Comment: I'll have to use that to save this headache happening again! Hate to do this but do you think you can checkout my other question that I was on before this problem sprung. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736173/edit-page-to-display-all-category-names-with-edit-inputs-on-each/ You seem like you would know exactly what to do

Comment: Sure, let me check it out

Comment: btw if the answer fixed it for you, you may wish to accept it so that others don't get confused

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add      `extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged` into my model. once it was added my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Just for your notice

You can rewrite [to_params](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method in your model to generate your uniq slug

```
to_params
 #for instance
  your_column + your_column
end
```